# How to extend time after max invalid attempt for Login (node-rate-limiter-flexible)

Tags: node.js, express, security

Basically i want to protect my login endpoint API from brute-force attack. The existing idea is when user consume max invalid attempt(suppose 5 retry) then i want to locked user and extend time for another each invalid attempt by 30 sec.

I am protecting that endpoint by node-rate-limiter-flexible package. (You can suggest best library for this)

```
const opts = {
  points: 5, // 6 points
  duration: 30, // Per second
};

const rateLimiter = new RateLimiterMemory(opts);

rateLimiter.consume(userid)
    .then((rateLimiterRes) => {
      // Login endpoint code
    })
    .catch((rateLimiterRes) => {
      // Too many invalid attempts
    });
```

Above code is working fine for max 5 invalid attempt and then blocked user for 30 second. But what i want to do that when user consumed max invalid attempt then for another each invalid attempt extend time by 30 sec. ((Means time will be gradually increase for each invalid attempt. maximum for 1 day). (Sorry for my ugly English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase `rateLimiterRes.msBeforeNext` on 30 seconds every time userId blocked and use [`rateLimiter.block`](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/API-methods#ratelimiterblockkey-secduration) method to setup new duration.

```
rateLimiter.consume(userid)
    .then((rateLimiterRes) => {
      // Login endpoint code
    })
    .catch((rateLimiterRes) => {
      const newBlockLifetimeSecs = Math.round(rateLimiterRes.msBeforeNext / 1000) + 30
      rateLimiter.block(userid, newBlockLifetimeSecs)
        .then(() => {
           // Too many invalid attempts
        })
        .catch(() => {
           // In case store limiter used (not in-memory)
        })
    });
```

There is also [example of Fibonacci-like increasing of block duration](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#dynamic-block-duration) on wiki